# Solidity "now" does not update in view function?

Tags: solidity

I've noticed that this always returns the same value:

```
 function getNow() public constant returns (uint) {
        return now;
    }
```

But when I use the `now` keyword in an function that changes the state of the network then it seems to work.

Can someone explain why this happens? Is there a way to use "now" in a `view` function?

Basically I'm just trying to set a timer and figure out how long the timer has left without paying any gas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [`now` is an alias for `block.timestamp`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties). In the context of a transaction, this is the timestamp of the block that the transaction is a part of. In a `call`, I believe the function is evaluated in the context of the latest block. In my testing, a function such as the one you described returns the timestamp matching the most recent block. If you call it repeatedly, you should see the return value change every time a new block is mined.

In any case, you don't need this for the purposes of your countdown... you can just use the current [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which you can easily get in JavaScript or any other programming language.

Answer (score 2):

`now` won't evaluate properly in view function. Reference (point 8): https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#functions

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Point 8 is "Using inline assembly that contains certain opcodes," which doesn't seem relevant. `now` certainly does not modify any state. Note that the code sample in the documentation shows a `view` function that uses `now`, and the Solidity compiler emits no warning for that code. See my answer for what I believe is the issue.

Comment: As I understood it, `now` is considered as an opcode in the example - it's the only non-constant (except the input variables which are totally ok in view functions). I interpreted that the example code is for the point 8.

Comment: I believe your interpretation was incorrect.